# Why is my dynamically generated id for a div element 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have collection of files and the corresponding titles to pdf uploads that is displayed on the screen. The user is able to delete this list.  Upon deletion of selected files, the list of files is supposed to be refreshed without reloading the page.  I am able to successfully perform an ajax request and get the files deleted and the server return the list of successfully deleted file as a json stirng.  My problem is, I cannot appear to jQuery select for dynamically generated div elements and delete them (specifically the div with 'id: id_name'). I am getting 'undefined' ids. Please can someone advise?

my dynamically generated content of files and their titles:

```
 $.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost/webservice/showlist.php',
  success: function(data){
      $.each(data, function(i, element){
          // display 'filename' and corresponding 'title'.
          var id_name = element['filename'];
          var id_title = element['title'];

          $('<div/>', {
              id: id_name
          })
          .append('<input type="checkbox" name="checkvalue[]"  disabled="disabled" class="check_box"'+id_name+'" value='+element['filename']+' >')
          .append('<div>' + id_name +'</div>')
          .append('<div class="clss_'+id_name+'">' + id_title +  '</div>')
          .appendTo(mainDiv);

        });
   }
```

This is part of the code that is executed when the 'Delete' button is pressed:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/webservice/delete_pdf.php',
            data: {delete_array: jsonString},
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                // Retrieve the success_delete array from json response.
                var toDelete_Array = data.success_delete;
                // Remove the filenames from the displayed list.
                //iterate through the success_delete array
               $.each(toDelete_Array,function(i, file_name){
                   // The id of each wrapper_div member is equal to corresponding filename
                   var x = $('#'+file_name).attr('id');
                   console.log('id for div: '+ x); <---- this returns 'undefined'

            // I have tried $('#'+file_name).remove(); and nothing happens. I am guessing it is due to the 'undefined' id of the div that i am trying to delete.
                });

                    },
            error: function(jqXHR, stringMessage, string){
                        alert(stringMessage);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: console.log your element and inspect it in developer tools:`console.log($('#'+file_name);`

Comment: Try $('<div/>', {`'id'`: id_name });

Comment: @ozili isn't that exactly what he has already?

Comment: What are the IDs? Using a file name - which could contain any number of special characters or spaces - doesn't seem like a good idea, and you're going to have to handle those explicitly if you do choose to do so.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist indeed not, but probably perfectly OK on HTML5 browsers.

Comment: @Alnitak Spaces are still invalid in the `id` attribute in HTML5 (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-id-attribute). Even if they were allowed, using a string "foo bar" to generate a jQuery selector - `$('#foo bar')` - isn't going to work, since that looks for an element of the tag `bar` inside an element with ID "foo".

Comment: i've found it convenient t this stage to use the filename as an id. but point taken. thanks. for the purpose of development my filenames are controlled and have no 'dodgy' characters.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist all good reasons - if the filenames are reasonably constrained it'd be OK, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My file_names had a period inside and this disrupted the jQuery selector operation. Periods are problematic for the jQuery selector because they are used to indicate class.   To solve this I escaped for it and other unwanted characters using the following function (taken from [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/)):

```
 $(clean_id(file_name)).fadeOut(2000,function(){
                       $(clean_id(file_name)).remove();
                   });

 function clean_id(my_id){
                       return "#" + my_id.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\]|,)/g, "\\$1" );
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't yet tell you from looking at the code why it's undefined, but *by definition* the ID of the element `$('#' + file_name)` must be exactly the value of `file_name`, i.e.:

```
var x = file_name;
```

If it remains undefined after that, then your `$.each` call is incorrect.